# Tense and 'had had'

Tags: past-tense

Which of these is correct? Instinctively, I'd say (1), but it feels a bit formal. I'm also tempted to use (3) but soften the double 'had' by using 'she'd' instead of 'she had'.

Thoughts? (Thank you!)

1. Anya would have smiled, had she the energy.
2. Anya would have smiled, if she had the energy.
3. Anya would have smiled, if she had had the energy.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing your #1 and #3 sentences, you can get a better-sounding one without the "had had" redundancy:

> Anya would have smiled, **had she had** the energy.

This is a usage of [type 3 conditional](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/type-3-conditional/) along with a ["shortened" conditional clause](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/conditional_sentences09.html).